# how to read list of letters into a 2D character array in c

Tags: c, arrays, file, loops, scanf

I am new to C so im sure there are many mistakes. I am trying to read a 9 by 9 sudoku "board" from a file, but instead of 1-9, A-I is used. I want to read this file into a character array so i can manipulate and loop through each element of the 2D character array to check that the sudoku is valid. this is what i have so far:

the text file looks like this:

E C D F G H I A B
F G B A I E C D H
A I H C D B E F G
H E I G F A D B C
D B F H E C G I B
G A C I B D H E F
H F A E C G B H D
B H G D A I F C E
C D E B H F A G I

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int i, j;
char **matsudoku = malloc(9*sizeof(char*));
for (i=0; i<9; ++i)
{
    matsudoku[i]=malloc(9*sizeof(char));
}

FILE *fpointer = fopen("C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Como Sci in C/sudokuchar.txt", "r");

if (fpointer == NULL)
{
    printf("Cannot open file \n");
    exit(0);
}

for(i=0; i<9; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<9; j++)
    {
            fscanf(fpointer, "%c", &matsudoku[i][j]);


            printf("%c", matsudoku[i][j]);

    }
}
printf("%c",matsudoku[0][0]);
fclose(fpointer);
free(matsudoku);
}
```

first of all all the number i use to pre-allocate space and loop through the file is 13 because using 9 and 9 (which i thought would work since the board is 9 by 9) was not printing the whole 9 by 9 board, the number 13 printed the whole board and "2=AMDE" for whatever reason. second, when i try to index into the matrix just to test if it read the file into the character array, i get random characters that change (ie. different letter that don't belong in the spot indexed, characters not even used in the Sudoku). what in the world can i do do to improve this code so it does something remotely close to what i want. anything helps, thanks

when i use 9 in the malloc functions and in the loops, the program prints:
E C D F G H I A B
F G B A I E C D H
A I H C D B E F G
H E I G F A D B C
D B F H E

Comment: The second `malloc` should be `malloc(13 * sizeof(char))`. But you really shouldn't use `13` instead you should use `9` for both `malloc` calls. You also need to `free` what you `malloc` once you're done with it.

Comment: ok thank you i did not know that about free. so at the end of the program i should have: free(matsudoku)??

Comment: also when i use 9 the program prints 4 lines with 9 rows and the 5th line only has 6 letters or rows any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: yes you should have `free(matsudoku)` after the `fclose` call. Does that happen even after fixing the second `malloc`? Not sure why that is happening, could you [edit] your question to include the contents of `sudokuchar.txt`?

Comment: Ok thanks @JonnyHenly, i added your suggestions and whats in the text file and what prints

Comment: `fscanf` is also reading spaces (`' '`) and new-line characters (`\n`) in your text file.

Comment: Use `fscanf(fpointer, " %c", &matsudoku[i][j]);` with one space in-between `"` and `%c`. This will tell `fscanf` to skip whitespace characters (`' '`, `\n`, `\t`, etc.).

Comment: yes thank you @JonnyHenly this worked!

Comment: No problem at all. Let me know if you need more help with this question.